# Add for loop results to excel spreadsheet with Python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, loops, export-to-excel

I am trying to create a small app which is identifying the names of the folders in a directory, and places those in a nice excel spreadsheet.

However, whenever I run the app, the results of the for loop are overwritten in the excel spreadsheet and I always end up with only one row, instead of all of the rows resulted from the loop.

Could you please have a look at my code and advise on what do I do wrong?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

CCM = "C:\Electronical Files\Drivers\CCM"

f = open("CCMs.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
f.close()

for crew in os.listdir(CCM):
    full_name = crew.split(", ")
    first_name = full_name[1]
    last_name = full_name[0]

    df = pd.DataFrame({"First name": [first_name], "Last name": [last_name]})
    df.to_excel("./CMMs.xlsx", sheet_name="CMMs")

    f = open("CCMs.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")
    f.write(crew + "\n")
    f.close()

    print(first_name + " " + last_name)
```

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold the dataframe creation and exporting to excel until after the loop is finished. Instead you can collect the names in a list that will be used to create the dataframe

```
names = []
for crew in os.listdir(CCM):
    names.append(crew.split(', ')[::-1])

df = pd.DataFrame(names, columns=['First Name', 'Last Name'])
df.to_excel('./CMMs.xlsx', sheet_name='CMMs')
with open('CCMs.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(names))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution Richie.
However, I get "sequence item 0: expected str instance, list_reverseiterator found" when running the app. It is related to the last line of code.

Comment: @AlexandruAna right, `join` cannot take generators (and you should've had a weird excel output as well), try it now with `[::-1]`

Comment: This seems to work! it just returns another error "sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found". Which way would you amend the code in order to write the individual items of the list?

Comment: I just removed the last 
"with open('CCMs.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(names))" and I managed to get the excel file I needed, with name an first name on two columns.
Many thanks!